# How to use multi value index when querying json array in Mysql 8.0.35?

Tags: mysql, json

### Environment

- Mysql 8.0.35

### My Situation

I want to get all rows if cancel.cancels[*].cancel_no is exactly "202401215050123". and also I want to use multi value index to optimize the query.

```sql
INSERT INTO pay.payment (payment_no, cancel) VALUES ('2024012150200010', '{"cancels": [{"cancel_no": "202401215050123", "amount": 100}]}');
```

### What I have tried so far

I started with fresh database.

```
SELECT VERSION(); -- 8.0.35--

CREATE DATABASE pay;

USE pay;

create table payment
(
    payment_no varchar(50) not null
        primary key,
    cancel     json        null
);


-- this does not work --
ALTER TABLE payment
  ADD INDEX cancel_no_idx ((
    CAST(cancel->>"$.cancels[*].cancel_no" as CHAR(255) ARRAY) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
  )) USING BTREE;


-- this works --
ALTER TABLE payment
  ADD INDEX cancel_no_idx ((
    CAST(cancel->>"$.cancels[*].cancel_no" as CHAR(255) ARRAY)
  )) USING BTREE;


-- insert a row --
INSERT INTO pay.payment (payment_no, cancel) VALUES ('2024012150200010', '{"cancels": [{"cancel_no": "202401215050123", "amount": 100}]}');

-- query  --
EXPLAIN SELECT cancel FROM payment WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(cancel, '{"cancel_no": "202401215050123"}', '$.cancels');
```

but the explain result says it's select_type is `SIMPLE`.

### My Question

- How do I make an index for this purpose and see if query is using the index?

Comment: Your `chancel_no` is NOT an array, it is common scalar value. Hence you'd use common index by the function.

Answer (score 2):

A solution which uses indexed generated column:

1. Create a table
2. Insert a row
3. Check the result

```
CREATE TABLE payment 
(
    payment_no varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    cancel     json        NULL
);

INSERT INTO payment 
VALUES ('2024012150200010', '{"cancels": [{"cancel_no": "202401215050123", "amount": 100}]}');

SELECT payment_no, JSON_PRETTY(cancel) 
FROM payment;
```

| payment_no | JSON_PRETTY(cancel) |
| --- | --- |
| 2024012150200010 | { "cancels": [ { "amount": 100, "cancel_no": "202401215050123" } ] } |

4. Add generated column which is defined as virtual (not stored, not need in disk space) and invisible (is not visible in any query which does not mention this column explicitly, so none existing queries needs in edition)
5. Add index by this column

```
ALTER TABLE payment
ADD COLUMN cancel_no VARCHAR(50)
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (cancel->>'$.cancels[0].cancel_no')
    VIRTUAL INVISIBLE,
ADD INDEX idx_cancel_no (cancel_no);
```

6. Add one more row
7. Check the result, with and without explicit generated column specifying (pay attention - the table contains 3 columns but we provide only 2 values, invisible column creation allows this because it is not listed explicitly)

```
INSERT INTO payment 
VALUES ('2024012150200011', '{"cancels": [{"cancel_no": "202401215050122", "amount": 100}]}');

SELECT * FROM payment;

SELECT payment_no, JSON_PRETTY(cancel), cancel_no 
FROM payment;
```

| payment_no | cancel |
| --- | --- |
| 2024012150200010 | 7b2263616e63656c73223a205b7b22616d6f756e74223a203130302c202263616e63656c5f6e6f223a2022323032343031323135303530313233227d5d7d |
| 2024012150200011 | 7b2263616e63656c73223a205b7b22616d6f756e74223a203130302c202263616e63656c5f6e6f223a2022323032343031323135303530313232227d5d7d |

| payment_no | JSON_PRETTY(cancel) | cancel_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024012150200010 | { "cancels": [ { "amount": 100, "cancel_no": "202401215050123" } ] } | 202401215050123 |
| 2024012150200011 | { "cancels": [ { "amount": 100, "cancel_no": "202401215050122" } ] } | 202401215050122 |

8. Check the query execution plan, ensure that the index is used.

```
-- query  --
EXPLAIN 
  SELECT cancel 
  FROM payment
  WHERE cancel_no = '202401215050123';
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | payment | *null* | ref | idx_cancel_no | idx_cancel_no | 203 | const | 1 | 100.00 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/llrDn7Xq)

Comment: Nice answer, However, what happens if there are multiple elements in $.cancels ?

Comment: @SelVazi OP tells about multi-valued index. But this index can be created only when the low-level attribute whose values should be indexed is JSON array. You tell about an array on the intermediate level - MVindex cannot be created in this case. Of course we can use according functions (JSON_TABLE then JSON_ARRAYAGG) and extract one definite attribute values in JSON array form and create MVindex by it. But this cannot be performed in generated column, trigger may do this.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for the answer! but I want to store multiple cancel in cancels array... and still I don't get the above comment of yours... can you please show me what happens when there are more than two `cancel` in the array?

Comment: @Jerry This is definitely another question which have another solution. I recommend you to create another topic and provide **adequate** sample data in it. of course you may refer to this question additionally.

Comment: hi @Akina, I created another question! could you please share me some insight? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77985137/how-to-use-multi-value-index-when-querying-json-array-array-o-object-in-mysql